# Will Website Developed On WampServer Localhost w/OpenSSL Require Changing SSL Certificate When Uploaded To Live Hosting?

Tags: wordpress, web, openssl, ssl-certificate, wampserver

I'm about to start developing an e-commerce website using WordPress that runs on a WampServer localhost on my laptop.  I want to use SSL in the WampServer localhost development environment and I'm leaning towards using OpenSSL.  Once I've completed the localhost website development, and I upload the website to production hosting, will I have to reconfigure the live website in order to support a different SSL certificate on the production hosting website?  I'm new to SSL and haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question.

Comment: For development purposes you can use a self signed certificate. There is no sense of purchasing a certificate for a development environment unless it uses the same domain name as the production one (e.g. dev.domain.com). You can also use your production domain on the development server and accessing it via your local hosts file.

Comment: @user1165759, thanks for the reply.  What I'm concerned about is having to change all of the WordPress permalinks after I upload the development site to the production site.  If I use a self-signed certificate during development, how much headache will I have when I upload the development site to the production site and have to change the self-signed certificate to the production certificate?  Will using the production certificate as the certificate for my development site eliminate this headache?

Comment: Well, you have two questions. For the latest, about using the production certificate, indeed this will eliminate the hassle of changing URLs in the data base but after you deploy you wont be able to use both environments simultaneously. For that there are several plugins (e.g., https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/, and others) that will let you change URLs after you deploy.

Comment: @user1165759, if I use the production SSL certificate on my WampServer localhost to prevent having to change permalinks when I upload the development website to production hosting, why wouldn't I be able to use both environments simultaneously since my WampServer localhost is a laptop behind my firewall that can't be seen on the public Internet?  I apologize for not mentioning that my WampServer development environment is a laptop placed behind my firewall.

Comment: Because to do that you will have to create a Virtual Host using the eventual Live domain name as the Virtual Host ServerName. To make that work you add a reference to your HOSTS file pointing "realdomain.com" to 127.0.0.1 to make that work on the local PC. Once you upload the site to the live site, in order for this Dev PC to be able to see the REAL live site you must remove that entry in the HOSTS file. So now when you put realdomain.com in your browser you will go to the real live site and NOT the local version.

Comment: I would ALWAYS recommend using a Virtual Host. The live environment you eventually buy is basically going to be a Virtual Host anyway unless you buy the whole server. It also makes the transition form DEV to LIVE so much more reliable. And now using WAMPServer 3 its a totally simple process to create one and then install wordpress into it.

Comment: Thanks, @RiggsFolly, for the explanation.  If my desired development environment is to use localhost for development only, and never use the live domain name during development (by modifying the HOSTS file), am I correct that I would use a different SSL certificate for the localhost development environment than the one that I will use for the production hosting environment (e.g., a self-signed cert for localhost and a commercial cert for production)?  I realize in this scenario that I will have to change the permalinks in the production hosting website, which I already know how to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, based on my last comment, do I need two separate SSL certs?  This is the only paid client website development project I ever expect to undertake (it's a favor to a former colleague).  I specifically DON'T want the client to have access to my dev environment - I'll be uploading milestone versions of the website to a staging URL on my hosting server for him to access when I'm ready for him to review my progress.